# Properly cancel JavaFX Task that launches ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am attempting to write a GUI application that performs many computationally intensive tasks. Because these tasks take some time, I would like to run them on multiple threads using an `ExecutorService`. However, waiting for these tasks to finish would freeze the UI, so I run that as a `Task` inside its own thread, which updates the UI on the progress of the `ExecuterService`. The user starts the tasks using the `Start` button, and should be able to cancel them with `Cancel`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

class DoWorkTask extends Task<List<Double>> {

    // List of tasks to do in parallel
    private final List<Callable<Double>> tasks;

    // Initialize the tasks
    public DoWorkTask(final int numTasks) {

        this.tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numTasks; ++i) {
            final int num = i;
            final Callable<Double> task = () -> {
                System.out.println("task " + num + " started");
                return longFunction();
            };

            this.tasks.add(task);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Double> call() {

        final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        // Submit all tasks to the ExecutorService
        final List<Future<Double>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tasks.forEach(task -> futures.add(executor.submit(task)));

        final List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();

        // Calling task.cancel() breaks out of this
        // function without completing the loop
        for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println("Checking future " + i);

            final Future<Double> future = futures.get(i);

            if (this.isCancelled()) {
                // This code is never run
                System.out.println("Cancelling future " + i);
                future.cancel(false);
            } else {
                try {
                    final Double sum = future.get();
                    result.add(sum);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        return result;
    }

    // Some computationally intensive function
    private static Double longFunction() {

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
            sum += Math.sqrt(i);
        }

        return sum;
    }

}

public class Example extends Application {

    final Button btnStart = new Button("Start");
    final Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
    final HBox box = new HBox(10, btnStart, btnCancel);
    final Scene scene = new Scene(box);

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        btnStart.setOnAction(event -> {

            final DoWorkTask task = new DoWorkTask(100);

            btnCancel.setOnAction(e -> task.cancel());

            task.setOnSucceeded(e -> System.out.println("Succeeded"));

            task.setOnCancelled(e -> System.out.println("Cancelled"));

            task.setOnFailed(e -> {
                System.out.println("Failed");
                throw new RuntimeException(task.getException());
            });

            new Thread(task).start();
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

However, upon starting the tasks and pressing the `Cancel` button, the `call()` function seems to end immediately without iterating over the rest of the futures. Some sample output.

```
task 0 started
task 1 started
task 2 started
Checking future 0
task 3 started
Checking future 1
task 4 started
Checking future 2
task 5 started
Cancelled
// Should continue to print Checking future x and
// Cancelling future x, but doesn't
task 6 started
task 7 started
task 8 started
task 9 started
...
```

None of the remaining futures are cancelled, and it seems they are not even iterated over; the `call()` function ends immediately. When the callables are not run inside an `ExecutorService`, but just sequentially inside the `DoWorkTask`, this problem doesn't occur. I am rather puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
try {
    final Double sum = future.get();
    result.add(sum);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

When you click on the button cancel, it actually cancels the main task `DoWorkTask` which interrupts the thread that executes the main task so as it is waiting for a result with `future.get()`, an `InterruptedException` is raised but with your current code you then throw a `RuntimeException` such that your main task exit immediately and thus cannot interrupt the sub tasks, you should continue when a `InterruptedException` is thrown.

```
try {
    final Double sum = future.get();
    result.add(sum);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // log something here to indicate that the task has been interrupted.
}
```

Comment: Thank you good sir. I didn't quite understand InterruptedExceptions before, and automatically turned it into an unchecked exception as I usually do.

Comment: A great article for understanding InterruptedExceptions is Brian Goetz's [Dealing with InterruptedException - You caught it, now what are you going to do with it?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/).